# Extension-Specific Context Menu

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add an item to the right-click menu on my extension. I've tried to find a method which would work, but a lot of the results seem to deal with context menus on the actual page, not the extension icon itself. The contextMenus API doesn't seem to work for this, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API for that. Head for [Chromium Issue 78631](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78631) and click the star to cast your vote for it and receive updates by e-mail. In the meantime, you could create a popup with a menu that lists both the primary action and the actions you would have put in the context menu.

(I assume you're trying to add the context menu item to your browser action. Your question is a little ambiguous.)

Comment: Aw man, I suspected as much. Basically, what I'm trying to do is have the extension button perform an action onclick, instead of showing a popup, which I've done and all. But then, it would show options when it's right clicked instead. I'll probably just use the options page for now, although it's more inconvenient.